# Theme translation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation, po

How can I translate the keywords that appear in blog like

Filter by, categories, tags, authors, Read more, all and others.. 
Here is the website I am working on http://pichuapp.com/ar/blog/

I am using WMPL plugin to translate the whole website posts and it's working efficiently. I am using the [betheme](http://themes.muffingroup.com/be/splash/) as wordpress templates.. I have read about .po files and downloaded the poedit but can't link it to the source file of the theme because it's online and can't get the keywords from online theme..

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

WPML offers an other way of translation: String Translation. Usually I do not bother with creating and / or modifying .po files, only use that feature of WPML, as it allows the user to scan the theme for strings that have a text-domain, and translate them through the admin interface.

You just have to install the String Translation plugin of WPML (only works if WPML is already installed), and start using it.